# Boost.Asio - polling a named pipe

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, named-pipes

I am trying to listen for input on a named pipe. I'm using Boost.Asio's [stream_descriptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/stream_descriptor.html) and [async_read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) under Linux. The problem is, the call to io_service::run() only blocks like I want it to until the first read. After that, it just keeps calling the handler immediately with the "End of file" error, even though I try to attach more async_reads to it. The code I have is equivalent to the following:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
int fifo_d = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDONLY);
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor fifo(io_service, fifo_d);
while (true)
{
    // buffer and handler probably aren't important for the purposes of this question
    boost::asio::async_read(fifo, buffer, handler);
    io_service.run();
}
```

Only the first async_read works as I expect it to. Subsequent async_reads just return immediately. The only way I found to make it work like I want is to close and reopen the named pipe, but it seems like a hack:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
while (true)
{
    int fifo_d = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDONLY);
    boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor fifo(io_service, fifo_d);
    boost::asio::async_read(fifo, buffer, handler);
    io_service.run();
    close(fifo_d);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Here's a simple "read" version, which allowed for some code simplification, the problem remains the same:

```
int fifo_d = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDONLY);
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor fifo(io_service, fifo_d);
while (true) {
    try {
        boost::asio::read(fifo, boost::asio::buffer(buffer));
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error& err) {
        // It loops here with "read: End of file" error
        std::cout << err.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how works. `run()` is not intended to be called in a loop. If you insist, you need to call `reset()` in between (as per the documentation).

Also, if you /want/ blocking behaviour, why are you using the `async_*` interface?

### Demos

1. Consider using a simple iostream to read the fd:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19e128b4deb57872)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>

   int main() {
       std::ifstream fifo("/tmp/fifo");

       std::string word;
       size_t lineno = 0;
       while (fifo >> word) {
           std::cout << "word: " << ++lineno << "\t" << word << "\n";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or if you **must** attach to some `fd` you get from somewhere else, use `file_descriptor` from Boost IOstreams:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1713bb2f42ce55df)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
   #include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fcntl.h>

   int main() {
       namespace io = boost::iostreams;
       using src = io::file_descriptor_source;
       io::stream<src> fifo(src(open("./fifo", O_RDONLY), io::file_descriptor_flags::close_handle));

       std::string word;
       size_t number = 0;
       while (fifo >> word) {
           std::cout << "word: " << ++number << "\t" << word << "\n";
       }
   }
   ```

Both examples print the expected:

```
word: 1 hello
word: 2 world
```

Comment: reset() doesn't really change anything for me. I intend to use async_read later on in my program, but you're right, for the purposes of my question a simple read is sufficient. I updated the question. Now, the code from your first sample (just reading from an ifstream) has pretty much the same effect - it blocks until I send some text to the pipe, prints that text and then exits immediately. What I want to do is to listen to input on that pipe indefinitely, so that any other program can send data to me at any time. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Ok, once again, reopening the pipe works:

    while (true) {
        std::ifstream fifo("/tmp/fifo");
        std::string line;
        while (fifo >> line) {
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
    }

So I assume that I misunderstand how named pipes are supposed to be used, not Asio.

Comment: @user2478832 Indeed. This simply indicates that the sending end of the pipe closes the pipe each time.

Comment: Ok, your answer helped me find my problem, so I'm accepting it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As also sehe reported, that's not the way boost::asio works.
The `ioservice::run()` method runs in blocking mode while it has some work. When the ioservice goes out of work you have to call the [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) method before putting other work, so that's why in your first code the async_read is done only once.

A common pattern in this case would look something like:

```
void handler(...) {
    if (!error) {
      // do your work
      boost::asio::async_read(fifo, buffer, handler); // <-- at the end of the handler a subsequent async_read is put to the ioservice, so it never goes out-of-work
    }
}

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
int fifo_d = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDONLY);
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor fifo(io_service, fifo_d);
boost::asio::async_read(fifo, buffer, handler); // <-- you call async_read only once here.
io_service.run(); //<-- this blocks till an error occurs
```

Comment: Thing is, he explicitly wants a blocking interface.

Comment: I have tried doing that, but it didn't work. After some experimenting, I have come to the loop I posted, to eliminate the possibility that my problem was somehow because I was trying to add an async_read from a handler. Anyway, that's pretty much the first version of the code that I had, and the if condition in handler was never invoked. Right on the first invocation, the handler would receive "End of file" error.