# Write and read boost into POSIX pipe (No boost.iostream)

Tags: c++, boost, posix, named-pipes

I have a setup that uses boost's serialization to archive objects to a file. I want/need to do the same but writing to POSIX pipes instead of basic files.

A simple packet:

```cpp
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include "AbstractPacket.hpp"

struct SimplePacket final: public AbstractPacket{
    bool value;

    BooleanPacket() noexcept = default;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& a, const unsigned int) {
        a& boost::serialization::base_object<AbstractPacket>(*this);
        a& value;
    }

    ~SimplePacket() = default;
};
```

Writing the simple packet:

```
#include "SimplePacket.hpp"
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(SimplePacket, "SimplePacket")
//...//
void write(Packet* packet){
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(_client_pipe, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(file);
        oa << packet;
        file.close();
    }
}
```

This writes the packet (boost serialized archive) to the file. However, I need to write to posix pipes.
I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34870502/10625647) that using boost.iostream is it possible to open a file stream to a POSIX pipe from its file descriptor.
I haven't found a clear way to do this; *but* I would like to do this **without using boost.iostream**, is such a thing possible, and if so how could I do it ?

Comment: What is the reason you so adamently assert you cannot use boost iostream? Your answer to that might invalidate every answer I was going to type. Don't just /claim/ things. Explain your motives, so we can help

Comment: @sehe The reason was mainly to try to see if there was a solution that existed native to cpp; I admit it could mean I would invalidate a lot of answers; sorry for the confusion ! (And thanks !)

Comment: FWIW Boost Iostream's support for stream descriptors is every bit as "native" as Asio's (which Process uses under the hood, just adding pipe creation in platform independent way).  I think I even remember it being part of the header-only subset of the library.

Comment: I [misremembered that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4d0a835e6f3fba9), but - you're using Boost serialization anyways... so you might as well. Other than this, there's obviously C code, so you can always "just write it yourself"

Comment: Here: [hail to "C-is-a-subset-of-C++" mantra](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8daddbd997012eb0)

Comment: @sehe I thought about C right away, but then I couldn't see how to write boost's serialized archive using C; hence trying to get an fstream on a pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together, Boost Asio + Process can also do this:

### Using Boost Process

**[Live On wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5jKiJ1fhl10agFVC)**

```
size_t write(Packet* packet) {
    boost::asio::streambuf sb;
    {
        std::ostream                    os(&sb);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os);
        oa << packet;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    boost::process::async_pipe p(ctx); // opens a pipe (pair of fds)

    size_t bytes = write(p, sb);       // throws system_error on error

    return bytes;
}
```

If you already have the pipe, use the appropriate constructor for `async_pipe` to pass the fds.

### Using Boost Asio Only

Also, if you already have the pipe fd, I'd suggest not using Boost Process at all:

```
boost::asio::io_context               ctx;
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor s(ctx, 2); // STDERR

size_t bytes = write(s, sb); // throws system_error on error
s.release();                 // to avoid close on destruction
```

In particular, note the `release()` that might save you time scratching your head.

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xTuQ8C63CuW7z6Yk)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

struct AbstractPacket {
    virtual ~AbstractPacket() = default;
    template <typename Archive> void serialize(Archive&, unsigned) {}
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(AbstractPacket)

struct BooleanPacket : public AbstractPacket {
    bool value;

    template <typename Archive> void serialize(Archive& a, unsigned) {
        a& boost::serialization::base_object<AbstractPacket>(*this);
        a& value;
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(BooleanPacket)

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

size_t write(AbstractPacket* packet) {
    boost::asio::streambuf sb;
    {
        std::ostream                    os(&sb);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
        oa << packet;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context               ctx;
    boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor s(ctx, 2); // STDERR

    size_t bytes = write(s, sb); // throws system_error on error
    s.release();                 // to avoid close on destruction

    return bytes;
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    auto test   = new BooleanPacket(); // please use smart pointers
    test->value = true;

    std::cout << "Bytes written: " << write(test) << "\n";

    delete test; // please use smart pointers
}
```

Prints stderr:

```
22 serialization::archive 18 1 13 BooleanPacket 1 0
0 1 0
1 1
```

And stdout:

```
Bytes written: 62
```

Comment: Boost is amazing